# How to install and use libnet in mac os?

Tags: osx-yosemite, libnet

I want to program in C with libnet in Mac OS.

When I type in `gcc *.o -o network -lnet`, there's an error:

> library not found for -lnet.

And when I use `homebrew` install linnet, is says:

> Warning: libnet-1.1.6 already installed.

Comment: Could you provide details on your library path? Where is libnet-1.1.6 located and is this location made available to you compiler through a -L parameter or the LD_LIBRARYPATH variable?

Comment: My path is: usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin , I just cannot find where the static library is .There are  'libnet.a', 'libnet.dylib' in /usr/local/lib. I add it to PATH, but it doesnot work.  Then I use -L to link libnet.a or libnet.dylib, gcc cannot find related symbols.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of library PATH.Flow the steps to solve this problem.
First, find where you install the library. For my case, the libnet is located in /usr/local/Cellar/libnet/1.1.6. 
Second, run /usr/local/Cellar/libnet/1.1.6/bin/libnet-config. 
Third, use -L to add the path when you link. 
gcc *.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/libnet/1.1.6/lib -lnet.